# Enterprise Architect generate SQL without quotes in table name

Tags: postgresql, database-design, enterprise-architect

I've created a database diagram in EA (12.0.1210) and I need to generate SQL script to create my PostgreSQL database schema. I noticed that table name is always in double quotes (`CREATE TABLE "Term"`) and therefore it is case sensitive.

Is there a way how to generate SQL script **without double quotes in table name**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Choose `Package/Database Engineering/Edit DDL Templates`
- Choose the Postgres DB from the dropdown
- Select the `DDL Create Table` macro
- Remove the `, "INCLUDE_SURROUND"` part on line 9

This EA proprietary language is awkward, to be polite.

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose Package/Database Engineering/Edit DDL Templates
2. Choose the Postgres DB from the dropdown
3. Select the `DDL Left Surround`
4. Remove `"` from template and save changes
5. Repeat steps 3-4 for `DLL Right Surround`

This removes `"` not only from `Create table`, but from all the templates including column names, views, table names in constraints, etc